# Approximation, $C^{1}$ function

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about approximation by $C^{1}$ fuctions.

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz continuous function.

**Question**

Let $\epsilon>0$. **Can we find a $C^{1}$ fucntion $G$ satisfies the following condition ? :** 
\begin{align*}
&\sup_{t \in[0,1]}|f(t)-G(t)|<\epsilon,\quad \int_{[0,1]}|f'(t)-G'(t)|dt<\epsilon\\
&G(0)=f(0),\quad G(1)=f(1) 
\end{align*}

**My attempt**

Since $f' \in L^{1}([0,1])$  and $C([0,1])$ is a dense subspace of $L^{1}([0,1])$, we can find $g \in C([0,1])$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]}|f'(t)-g(t)|dt<\epsilon
\end{align*}
Define $\displaystyle G(t):=f(0)+\int_{[0,t]}g(t)dt$. It is easy to show that
\begin{align*}
G \in C^{1}([0,1]),\quad \sup_{t \in[0,1]}|f(t)-G(t)|<\epsilon,\quad G(0)=f(0)
\end{align*}
Can I adjust $G$ such that $G(0)=f(1)$ ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\xi\equiv f(1)-G(1)$. Note that $|\xi|<\varepsilon$. Now define $$H(t)\equiv G(t)+t\xi\quad\forall t\in[0,1].$$ Clearly, $H(0)=G(0)=f(0)$ and $H(1)=f(1)$ by construction. Moreover, $$\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|H(t)-f(t)|\leq\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|H(t)-G(t)|+\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|G(t)-f(t)|<|\xi|+\varepsilon<2\varepsilon,$$ and $$H'(t)=G'(t)+\xi=g(t)+\xi\quad\forall t\in[0,1]$$ (considering one-sided derivatives at endpoints), so that $$\int_{[0,1]}|f'(t)-H'(t)|\,\mathrm dt\leq\int_{[0,1]}|f'(t)-g(t)|\,\mathrm dt+\int_{[0,1]}|g(t)-H'(t)|\,\mathrm dt<\varepsilon+|\xi|<2\varepsilon.$$ Therefore, $H$ satisfies the desired conditions (after replacing $\varepsilon$ with $2\varepsilon$, which is without loss of generality).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your answer is very easy to understand.

Comment: @sharpe Thank you, the pleasure is mine!